# Javascript & CSS - opening menu has glitchy transition

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I have some code that glitches initially when menus are expanded on top of each other.

If you select option two in the first menu, the second option appears. If you *then* go to open the first menu, you will see it glitches as it opens - there is almost a shutter-like delay. Maybe it has something to do with the z index setting, I'm not sure?

In firefox and chrome, there is no (apparent) glitch. In safari, the snippet below, there is a glitch.

Why is it glitching?

```js
const selected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".options-container");

for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
  selected[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    optionsContainer[i].classList.toggle("open");
    selected[i].classList.toggle("open");

    for (let j = 0; j < selected.length; j++) {

      if (i != j && selected[j].classList.contains("open")) {
        optionsContainer[j].classList.toggle("open");
        selected[j].classList.toggle("open");
      }
    }
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < optionsContainer.length; i++) {
  let optionsList = optionsContainer[i].querySelectorAll(".options");

  for (let j = 0; j < optionsList.length; j++) {
    optionsList.forEach(o => {
      o.addEventListener("click", () => {
        selected[i].innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
        optionsContainer[i].classList.remove("open");
        selected[i].classList.remove("open");
        if (document.getElementById("level").innerText.indexOf('one') === -1) {
          document.getElementById("tier").style.display = "grid";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("tier").style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.filter-filterbox-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "question select-box";
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.filter-filterbox-row .question {
  grid-template-areas: "question";
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}

.filter-filterbox-row .select-box {
  margin-left: -100px;
  grid-template-areas: "select-box";
}

.select-box {
  width: 200px;
}

.select-box .options-container {
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid #253e5c;
  border-radius: 0 0 4.5px 4.5px;
}

.selected {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #cdcccc;
  border-radius: 4.5px;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.selected.open {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 4.5px 4.5px 0 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border-color: #253e5c
}

.selected::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(media/dropdown-black.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 12px;
  right: 13px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.selected.open::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  top: -11px;
}

.select-box .options-container.open {
  border-color: #253e5c;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}

.select-box .options-container.open .options:nth-child(n+2) {
  border-top: 1px solid #253e5c;
}

.select-box .options-container .options {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.select-box .options:hover {
  background: #76bc6b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box .options .radio {
  display: none;
}

#tier {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-filterbox-row" id="level">
  <div class="question"> Level </div>
  <div class="select-box">
    <div class="selected">
      Select level
    </div>

    <div class="options-container">

      <div class="options">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="1" name="level">
        <label for="1">one</label>
      </div>

      <div class="options">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="2" name="level">
        <label for="2">two</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filter-filterbox-row" id="tier">
  <div class="question"> Select tier </div>
  <div class="select-box">
    <div class="selected">
      Select tier
    </div>

    <div class="options-container">

      <div class="options">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="bronze" name="tier">
        <label for="bronze">Bronze</label>
      </div>

      <div class="options">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="silver" name="tier">
        <label for="silver">silver</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what browser does the problem manifest? I don't see it in Chrome...

Comment: Oh of course, the snippet is browser dependent. It is definitely a problem in safari,  I will recheck the other two right now. Edit: ok yes, no problem in chrome or firefox, my mistake.

Comment: Had a z-index issue in safari aswell recently. Try adding `transform: translate3D(0,0,0);` to your css. Sounds hacky but solved it for me

Comment: This was one of the things I have tried, but it only seems to amplify the issue and extend the period of the glitch if I add the transform with the z-index setting still in. If I add that transform without a z index setting, the menu does not overlay (perhaps expectedly) and the result is a weird static blend of the menu with the rest of the background.

Comment: cant test, but my suspicion is that this is caused by the fact you are using a label, associated with a radio input that is `display:none`. When you select the option I am guessing that Safari is attempting to apply focus to this radio input (as you shouldn't have a visible label associated with an input that is `display:none`). Try changing the radio input to `opacity:0` in your CSS and see if the problem persists. This isn't a fix but may confirm my suspicions and let you know what to focus on.

Comment: Perhaps you can visit this site and check what's wrong with your markup or style sheet: https://validator.w3.org/  If you find it, correct your mistakes and then check about the glitch in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `position: relative;` to the class `.filter-filterbox-row` would fix it immediately for Safari:

```css
.filter-filterbox-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "question select-box";
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  position: relative;
}
```

`position: static;` is the default normal flow of the document if not explicitly stated. Since you've declared a `z-index: 99` on the child div:

```css
.select-box .options-container.open {
  border-color: #253e5c;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

...stating the z-index assumes the div is in absolute position, thus we need to declare a position for the parent div which is the `.filter-filterbox-row`. Furthermore, adding the `position: absolute;` on the child div is required if you need to state the `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` properties.

Declaring an explicit position for the parent div is one way to prevent different browser behavior glitches such as this. The same practice we always do when we declare a z-index on the child div and state the position as relative, the parent div should be declared as well with the position if relative or absolute for the child div to behave accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a delay setting your z-index within the Safari browser, when doing it with CSS.

Setting it with JavaScript resolves the issue:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('select-box')[0].style.zIndex = 99;
```

**Snippet:**

```js
const selected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".options-container");

for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
  selected[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    optionsContainer[i].classList.toggle("open");
    selected[i].classList.toggle("open");
    document.getElementsByClassName('select-box')[0].style.zIndex = 99;
    for (let j = 0; j < selected.length; j++) {
      if (i != j && selected[j].classList.contains("open")) {
        optionsContainer[j].classList.toggle("open");
        selected[j].classList.toggle("open");
      }
    }
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < optionsContainer.length; i++) {
  let optionsList = optionsContainer[i].querySelectorAll(".options");

  for (let j = 0; j < optionsList.length; j++) {
    optionsList.forEach(o => {
      o.addEventListener("click", () => {
        selected[i].innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
        optionsContainer[i].classList.remove("open");
        selected[i].classList.remove("open");
        if (document.getElementById("level").innerText.indexOf('one') === -1) {
          document.getElementById("tier").style.display = "grid";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("tier").style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.filter-filterbox-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "question select-box";
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.filter-filterbox-row .question {
  grid-template-areas: "question";
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}

.filter-filterbox-row .select-box {
  margin-left: -100px;
  grid-template-areas: "select-box";
}

.select-box {
  width: 200px;
}

.select-box .options-container {
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid #253e5c;
  border-radius: 0 0 4.5px 4.5px;
}

.selected {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #cdcccc;
  border-radius: 4.5px;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.selected.open {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 4.5px 4.5px 0 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border-color: #253e5c
}

.selected::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(media/dropdown-black.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 12px;
  right: 13px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.selected.open::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  top: -11px;
}

.select-box .options-container.open {
  border-color: #253e5c;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}

.select-box .options-container.open .options:nth-child(n+2) {
  border-top: 1px solid #253e5c;
}

.select-box .options-container .options {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.select-box .options:hover {
  background: #76bc6b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box .options .radio {
  display: none;
}

#tier {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-filterbox-row" id="level">
  <div class="question"> Level </div>
  <div class="select-box">
    <div class="selected">
      Select level
    </div>

    <div class="options-container">

      <div class="options">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="1" name="level">
        <label for="1">one</label>
      </div>

      <div class="options">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="2" name="level">
        <label for="2">two</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filter-filterbox-row" id="tier">
  <div class="question"> Select tier </div>
  <div class="select-box">
    <div class="selected">
      Select tier
    </div>

    <div class="options-container">

      <div class="options">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="bronze" name="tier">
        <label for="bronze">Bronze</label>
      </div>

      <div class="options">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="silver" name="tier">
        <label for="silver">silver</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I picked the other answer simply because they involved pure CSS fixes :)

Comment: You're welcome & fair enough! I also prefer the pure CSS answer haha :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your snippet, I think something has to do with `transform` within the pseudo-element and `transition: all 0.4s;` on most of the elements:

```
.selected.open::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  top: -11px;
}
```

I have two options to fix this:

**Option #1: Add z-index to each of `.filter-filterbox-row` elements.**

```
.filter-filterbox-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "question select-box";
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  position: relative;  // NEW: Relative position.
  z-index: 0;  // NEW: Default z-index value.
}
// NEW: Set higher z-index for parent dropdown.
.filter-filterbox-row#level {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**Option #2: Change transform value in `.selected::after`.**

```
.selected::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(media/dropdown-black.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 12px;
  right: 13px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;  // UPDATE: Change 'all' to 'transform'.
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was very useful as an alternative suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you use nested `<details>` and `<summary>` instead?

https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-that-details-summary-is-the-easiest-way-ever-to-make-an-accordion/